# Can you choose #define based on parameter?

Tags: c, directive

To simplify a commonly occurring bitmap lookup, I decided to write a macro for it.  This macro would take in parameters array, position, and number of bits per entry.  The latter is always 1, 2, or 3, to be determined at compile time.

The macros for one and two bits per entry are quite simple:

```
#define 1BITLOOKUP(array, index) (array[index / CHAR_BIT] >> (index % CHAR_BIT)) & 1
#define 2BITLOOKUP(array, index) (array[2 * index / CHAR_BIT] >> (2 * index % CHAR_BIT)) & (0x11)
```

However, three-bit bitmap will be more complex, since it will cross byte boundaries.  For the sake of efficiency, I do not wish to include that code when I am only using one- and two- bit lookups.  So I would like to use a macro of the sort

```
#define BITMAPLOOKUP(array, index, k) kBITLOOKUP(array, index)
```

However, this does not work.  Is there a workaround?

NOTE: This has been updated to a non-minimal working example, as per request of multiple commenters.

Comment: `##` might work: `#define FUNCTION(k) FUNCTION ## k`. Even if this does work, you can only do it by literal (i.e., you can't use a variable from your code). Another way is to use function pointers and do the selection dynamically in your code. Without more information, it would be hard to help.

Comment: Why do you think `#define` is  a function? Also why do this - just to make code unreadable?

Comment: @EdHeal. Good call, this does look like a potential XY problem. OP, please provide more information.

Comment: First, those aren't functions; they're preprocessor macros. Second, how does passing a constant as a macro argument make this *any* easier than specifying a different macro name in the first place? Whether you somehow used `FUNCTION(1)` or `FUNCTION1`, you're still typing `FUNCTION` and you're still typing `1`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Maybe instead of `1` he uses another macro: `#define BLAH 1` then `FUNCTION(BLAH)`

Comment: There is only one function and that is `printf`! A macro is no way a function. And this is an XY problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist How do you make a dynamic function selection in the code?  Do you have an example?

Comment: If you need to choose at runtime, you'd generally use real functions (as opposed to preprocessor macros) and an array of function pointers you index into. But I suspect there's a better solution for you, so tell us what your end goal is.

Comment: @Kevin OK.  I updated it.  Though I still don't understand, why in this case not asking the "minimal working example" is not the desired thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MadPhysicist suggests something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void func0(void) { printf("0\n"); }
static void func1(void) { printf("1\n"); }
static void func2(void) { printf("2\n"); }
static void func3(void) { printf("3\n"); }

static void (*func[])(void) = {func0, func1, func2, func3};

int main(void)
{
    func[1]();
    return 0;
}
```

This has an advantage: you are not limited to compile time literals:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     FUNCTION(i); /* invalid */
     func[i](); /* valid */
}
```

Comment: What is the effect of the `(void)` when you say `func0(void)`?

Comment: (void) = Without parameters

Comment: Why not just say `()` then?

Comment: () = can take anything for its arguments

Comment: I never heard that...  can you give a reference so I can read where the passed arguments would go for a `()` function?

Comment: I fully endorse this message:)

Comment: @MadPhysicist It looks like both of the answers to this question are based off of your single comment.  Now *that*, is pretty genius. :D

Answer (score 4):

You can paste the macro argument into other words without separator, using the `##` construct. So here this will work:

```
#define FUNCTION(k) FUNCTION##k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw45LOSU1LTMvVcEt1M85xNPfz1ChoCgzryRNQyktP19JE0PeCC6flFiERd4YLh@TB5TGkNfI1oSzlZWzubiAihVyEzPzFDQ0Faq5OOHqDDWtkXhGKDxjIK/2/38A)

Comment: I read that after wrote my answer. I do not know why others answer in comments?

Comment: The real functional solution is also a good one, and more usual. There can be cases though when you want to solve it in compile time, for example performance reasons, also when the other function is never invoked in that place, eg. developing for different architectures. It is also possible in this case that the other function not even exists on that arch.